# Ruby error handling: Rescuing Exceptions in Subclasses

Tags: ruby, inheritance, error-handling, custom-error-handling, airbrake

I have a collection of Adpapter classes that connect to various APIs and what not. Here is a simple, general example of how each adapter is set up:

```
class AmazonAdapter
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(id)
        get_results_from_api(id)
    end
end

class WalmartAdapter
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(id)
        get_results_from_api(id)
    end
end
```

So generally, by calling `AmazonAdapter.new(500)`, it is going to connect to the API and return results subject to what you pass in as the ID. This is all part of a Sidekiq collection process and run as a background job, so it won't necessarily throw obvious exceptions or errors to alert me when something went wrong.

I would like to use AirBrake's notification system to notify me when the API's don't connect properly or if any other errors were thrown, but without stopping the collection process or sidekiq. I was hoping to mainstream the error handling and notification system.

Some thoughts I have are to create a ParentClass that the subclasses can inherit from that looks something similar to this:

```
class Adapter
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(id)
        begin
            #execute subclass perform method
        rescue Exception => e
            Airbrake.notify(e)
        end
    end
end
```

But I am not really sure on the best way to go about this. I could really use some advice or help on this one, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bottleneck in `Sidekiq` that basically executes everything: [`Sidekiq::Processor#execute_job`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/be3073afc3926575be0984fa671eb92325066e93/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb#L154), that receives two arguments `(worker, cloned_args)` and subsequently calls `worker.perform(*cloned_args)`. So, for your purpose I would go with prepending the module to it:

```
Sidekiq::Processor.prepend(Module.new do
  def execute_job(worker, cloned_args)
    super # CALL ORIGINAL
  rescue => e # NEVER RESCUE FROM EXCEPTION!!!
    Airbrake.notify(e) # NOTIFY
    raise e # RE-RAISE SO SIDEKIQ DOES HIS JOB
  end
end)
```

Call this before your first job and you are done: all errors, happened during Sidekiq’s calling workers are now airbraked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out. I understand that you never want to rescue an Exception. But I am running an application that does one thing, and that one thing is to collect data through a pipeline system (implemented with fibers/threads). Once one worker is fired, it fires hundreds of jobs simultaneously, and with it being a sidekiq execution, I am not notified of collections that didn't happen. I don't necessarily want it to throw an exception because I want to keep the workers running. When you say "So sidekiq does his job," do you mean let him keep retrying jobs?

Comment: ‘When you say "So sidekiq does his job," do you mean let him keep retrying jobs?’—Yes. Sidekiq will either retry or silently skip retries depending on `retry: true|false` parameter specified in `Worker` implementation. BTW, rescueing `Exception` makes not much sense, since `OutOfMemory` and other `Exception` are not handable in general.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar construct to alert me to failures in some chron jobs and ping a slack channel, but the good part is it doesn't require inheritance! A naive version of that would look something like this:

```rb
class AirbrakeNotifier
  def safe_run
    yield
  rescue StandardError => e
    log_error(e)
    raise e
  end

  private

  def log_error(e)
    # do your logging here
  end
end
```

And then your workers would look something like this:

```
class AmazonAdapter
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    AirbrakeNotifier.new.safe_run { get_results_from_api(id) }
  end
end
```

This gives you much more flexibility to configure logging in different ways that you want per class, per process, or really however you can think!

Comment: Hey Devon! Long time no see, hope all is well! That's awesome, I'm going to look into this!